# Android Studio: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError from boilerpipe

Tags: java, android, android-studio, web-scraping, boilerpipe

I am trying to use boilerpipe for getting text article like the pocket app. App compile properly but gives runtime exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeHTMLParser
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput.getTextDocument(BoilerpipeSAXInput.java:51)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:69)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:87)
    at com.example.pushpankar.fastreader.ReadView$fetchUrlTxt.doInBackground(ReadView.java:154)
    at com.example.pushpankar.fastreader.ReadView$fetchUrlTxt.doInBackground(ReadView.java:147)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here are the things that i have already tried:

1. Clean and build project
2. gradlew clean
3. Add library by different methods

I saw same bug has been posted on the github.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pushpankar.fastreader"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
       release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        } 
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    compile project(':boilerpipe-1.2.0-android')
    compile project(':xerces-for-android')
    compile project(':nekohtml')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError for code in an Java library on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android)

Comment: I have similar approach for android studio but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are using some obfuscator which renames it to other characters and this gives error ?

Comment: I don't think that i am using any "obfuscator". I have heard of this term for first time.

Comment: obfuscator is used for shrinking code/resource in android example proguard, Can you confirm that  BoilerpipeHTMLParser is in the correct pakage??

Comment: Yes BoilerpipeHTMLParser is in the package.

Comment: When i open that file androd studio says decompiled .class file, bytecode version : 49.0 (java 5.0). Is this anyhow related to my problem?

Comment: that should not be the problem ,do one thing ,clear C:\Users\.gradle\cache   after delete do then clean the solution and see