# Error on installing on Samsung smartphone after app release (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java, android

After releasing an app update, I'm having these errors on app opening:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5024)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4633)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4573)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5009)
```

and

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:0)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:0)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5021)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4633)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4573)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
```

Only on these smartphone:

**Galaxy S3 Neo Plus (s3ve3g)

Galaxy Core2 (kanas3gnfc)

Galaxy S4 Mini (serranolte)**

Someone can help me?

Comment: check once does this app working well before and after marshmallow devices means  irrespectives of versions

Comment: You can take some help from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android

Comment: Maybe this devices have old google play services on them, and they not compatible with firebase.