# gcm not working when used with aws GCMIntentService Noclassdeffounderror

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging

I am writing android application which uses both google cloud messaging(GCM) registration and AWS S3 for different purposes. My application crashes when I have aws S3 jar files on build path and the method register is called on GCMIntentService. The error displayed is:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.mydomain.mypackage, PID: 30234
                                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mydomain.myPackage.GCMIntentService
                                                                        at com.mydomain.myPackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Are you saying that by just adding the s3 jar file, this error occurs?

Comment: Yes, i tested it by removing the aws-android-sdk-core , s3 and cognito jar files. It works fine then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError for code in an Java library on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android)