# how to fix 'NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: ActivityName'

Tags: android, gradle, runtime-error, google-play-services

My app crashes at the time of beginning and generates the below error.

> The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

So in order to fix an error I changed the build.gradle(project level) from

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'`
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
```

and build.gradle(app level)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
```

After change of above gradle code, my project is running well without the below error.

> The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

But the above gradle changes create another error which is created at runtime when we call activity from one to another which I'm not able to solve, which is as below.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/..../insta/InstaSplashActivity;

Here, `InstaSplashActivity` is an activity that will be called from the first activity, which is creating a crash.

Comment: Did you try, Invalidate caches and restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is fixed by simply uninstalling quick-heal.

**quick-heal not permit to run dex files and at the time of running it automatically repair some back-end files of an android studio so, android studio cannot getting files properly so i'm removed quick-heal completely and now my project work well :)**

Answer (score 0):

Based from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError), this was thrown:

> If the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in
> the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part
> of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition
> of the class could be found.

There are solutions offered from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android):

> - Go to "Properties" of the project.
> - Select "Java Build Path"
> - Select "Order and Export" Tab
> - You should see the selected project's "src" and "gen" paths and dependencies here.
> - The order how they listed were first "src" and then "gen" path
> - I switch them, so that "gen" folder is build before the "src"
>
> **gen** - automated code in project (from dependencies and references)
>
> **src** - source code in project
>
> or
>
> Try going to **Project** -> **Properties** -> **Java Build Path** -> **Order &**
> **Export** and ensure Android Private Libraries are checked for your
> project and for all other library projects you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your line

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
```

Build the project

Add this line

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'

build again

Also still not work , get add your line through dependency from module setting