# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.stage.StagingManager$1, even though the class exists in the jar file

Tags: java, android, symmetricds

I am trying to integrate Symmetric-Android 3.10.2 in my Android application. It is showing

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.stage.StagingManager$1

Even the class exists in jarfile

I have upgraded my API level from 22 to 26 after reading article from
https://sourceforge.net/p/symmetricds/discussion/1354726/thread/f965364c00/
but the issue remains

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.stage.StagingManager$1
>           at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.stage.StagingManager.(StagingManager.java:288)
>           at org.jumpmind.symmetric.android.AndroidSymmetricEngine.createStagingManager(AndroidSymmetricEngine.java:108)
>           at org.jumpmind.symmetric.AbstractSymmetricEngine.init(AbstractSymmetricEngine.java:348)
>           at org.jumpmind.symmetric.android.AndroidSymmetricEngine.(AndroidSymmetricEngine.java:84)
>           at org.jumpmind.symmetric.android.SymmetricService.onStartCommand(SymmetricService.java:88)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3944)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:219)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1833)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Comment: There might be an error in the jar file. try re adding the relevant jar.

Comment: Downloaded the 3.10.2 version from their website, replaced it and still the problem remains

Comment: if i were you, firstly will try to invalidate caches and restart bcz of there might be chances leading jar files causing losing or conflict while updating version

Comment: Have done that as well
also tried 3.10.0
3.10.1
all of them gives the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue may not be related to SymmetricDS, but instead how your classpath is configured in this Android project. There are several solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android) that might help