# SDK manager not starting

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

When i click on SDK manager in the eclipse, it does not start. Rather it displaying following message

**`Android\tools\lib\\find_java.exe` `-s'` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"**

I tried to change my Path variable, but it still does not work. Not sure what mistake I am doing. Appreciate your help.

My path variable contains:

JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0

`C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin`

Thanks

Comment: Can you try runniong Eclipse or the seperate SDK manage exe file as Administrator? This usually works for me in this case, but isn't a fix all.

Comment: @RossC I tried running the SDK manager as admin, but it dint help. First and foremost I am not sure what value to be added path in Environment variable for JAVA

Comment: Inside tool-> lib-> find_java.exe is ran, it displays "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 " . I have added the same with \bin at the end to the path variable.

Comment: Tried these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234403/sdk-manager-exe-doesnt-work-android  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095322/android-eclipse-classpath-want-to-add-classpath-container-path-but-eclipse-won  Might help. Also did you get the full ADK itself (that includes Eclipse) or did you set it all up seperately?

Comment: remove path variable,add it again with desired values,and restart the pc,now start sdk,think it will work

Comment: also look for residual `.android` folder lying around which you might have used,remove it

Comment: @KaranMer what values exactly need to be added to the JAVA_HOME and in path variable fr java? 
Where can i find the .android ?

Comment: @RossC yes i got the full SDK with the eclipse, as you see above in my ques, i am using jdk1.7.0 . I think some problem with my environment variables which is causing me this prob. But I am not sure what values in the environment variable.

Comment: set JAVA_HOME = your jdk bin directory. Also add the jdk bin directory to your path.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\user.android you can find it here in win 7

Comment: @RossC I have updated my JAVA_HOME and path in my Question. with those changes it still does not start SDK manager :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is a problem with the find_java.bat file. Please refer to the thread here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28196

Comment: Did u get the answer finally?. I'm also facing the same problem for last two days

Comment: update the SDK via command line using the command android "update sdk --no-ui "

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

Open up /tools/android.bat in your favorite text editor

Search for this piece of code:

```
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

Replace it with this:

```
set java_exe="<Path of your JDK>\bin\java.exe"
```

java_exe will be the static path is the path to your Java exe.

Run android.bat

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the solution your looking for, but when I set file path variables I use 2 backslashes instead of one. So it would be

```
C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\bin;
D:\\Android-SDK\\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130911\\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130911\\sdk\\tools;
C:\\Program Files\\PC Connectivity Solution\\;
```

Comment: Worth a try I suppose :) sorry It wasn't of use