# Eclipse SDK Manager Not Showing up

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I'm using Windows-7 64 bit and I have installed this(jdk-7u45-windows-x64) updated JDK in my system. My SDK was updated upto API level 18(Android 4.3).

When i click on SDK manager in the eclipse, it does not start. I tried open it directly with Administrator permission also. But it does not start. I had tried to set the variable path like these. 
[image] [image]
But I'm always getting the same error like this. 
[image]

After I found that in my **find_java.exe** get the java path from windows\system32 as shown below [image].

How can I set the Java path to my installed java folder.

Need some one help to figure it out. For Reference look at this link also.
[SDK manager not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891173/sdk-manager-not-starting#)

Comment: Have you got the correct path to your Java bin folder in your Windows PATH Environment variable?

Comment: http://geeklabs.co.in/android/Setup4ADE.html   this may help you,i think...

Comment: we can't see \bin in the in path...

Comment: what is error you've received while you try.

Comment: @ManetiVinay I have tried adding the \bin in the path. but it shows the same error.

Comment: once you try to uninstall and reinstall the java with different version...

Comment: @ManetiVinay It shows my java is calling from system32 folder. see the above screen shot. Need your help to call java from my installed location

Comment: i think we cannot update, we need to install First of all JDK..and after you can do any think..

Comment: add ";" in the end of your path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While setting the environment variable try JAVA_HOME variable pointing the bin directory.

because the android checks the java.exe in particular path.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to android,As long as i studied ,Android requires Java 1.5 or 1.6. You are using 1.7
Google does not add complete jdk 1.7 support to android system requirement(some api are exception) .. It does not mean that you should not have jdk 1.7. you should also have 1.6 jdk for compiler compilance. it is a better way to avoid using 1.7 jdk ,if u dont want jdk 1.7 features.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html see the system requirements and even if u developed using 1.7...when you installing your app in real device .we may face signing issue.
you may use some jar file which targetting java 1.7. but android system runtime(dalvik jvm) does not know how to process those files which means dex tool wont process those files which belongs to 1.7 and it wont create classes.dex file..hope it will help somehow

Answer (score 0):

From  the error you have posted it seems the problem is only with the path settings.

Add the path upto the *bin folder of your jdk* - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin and restart the eclipse.

Comment: I have tried adding the \bin in the path. but it shows the same error.

Comment: Wierd...!! Try restarting your machine once.....It might help. If it not, then Add the path from command prompt itself - PATH=%PATH%;jdk path and try. Note that this will help you add the path for that instance only and not permanently.

Comment: Also once you set the path, try "echo %PATH%" just to check the path is set correctly and then try your process.
If it's correct and still not working, make sure there is a javac in that directory by trying:

"c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\javac.exe"
from the command prompt.

Comment: It shows my java is calling from system32 folder. see the above screen shot. Need your help to call java from my installed location

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if your SDK Location in the Window->Preferences->Android points to the correct SDK path.

Comment: Hope it was working earlier and only stopped working after your upgraded your SDK to API18. Typically you would require to update your ADT version as well. And also in parallel check if the SDKManager.exe resides inside in the SDK path.

Comment: Yes @VikramV. It was working before. I have updated my ADT version to 22.3.0. Can you please explain clearly about the last point?

Comment: I meant for you to check if your SDKManager.exe file is in SDK path.
Typically: <sdk-location path>\SDK Manager.exe

Comment: It shows my java is calling from system32 folder. see the above screen shot. Need your help to call java from my installed location

Comment: Please check your environment variable to see if it points to the right location
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
JRE_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Both the above should be in User Variables
Below should be done in System Variables
Path - _Add_ `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;` _at the start_

Answer (score 0):

Download latest android bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

and replace new sdk folder with old sdk folder from android bundle folder.

now it's may work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Reinstalled my OS and Installed JDK 1.6. Then I have added my updated SDK to my ADT. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and this solved it

[image]
[image]
[image]